# Cordova Windows Phone URL Association

Tags: url, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a plugin for my Cordova application that adds support for URL association, so my app can be launched from let's say, bob://test/some/stuff  This works for Android and iOS.

How would I add Windows Phone support?

It's being written in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 with CTP Hybrid Tools 2.